# Assigning to a token list register without a `=` sign

Tags: tex-core, token-lists

I've noticed that it is possible to assign a value to a token list register without using `=` (the equality sign) as follows:

```
\newtoks\mytoks%
\mytoks{Hello, world!}% as opposed to \mytoks={Hello, world!}
```

However, according to the TeXbook, the `=` is mandatory.

Is this a known extension, or is this a bug in `pdftex`?

Comment: Where in the TeXbook are you citing that the `=` is mandatory?  The example on p.212?  In general, for many (every?) TeX command that employs the `=` for assignment, the `=` can be omitted.  Lengths, for example.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, the first paragraph on p. 212. It's not an example, it's a normative statement: "To assign a new value to a token list parameter or register, you say ...". So is this a documented feature?

Comment: This page is only a description, the rules are on page 275, there `<equal>`  is describes as optional spaces or optional spaces and =.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 275 of the TeXbook:

"Assignment commands often include an = sign, but in all cases this sign is optional; you can leave it out if you don't mind the fact that the resulting TeX code might not look quite like an assignment."